# Compare two arrays and create new array with equal elements in C

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm

The problem is to check two arrays for the same integer value and put matching values in a new array.

Let say I have two arrays

`a[n] = {2,5,2,7,8,4,2}`
`b[m] = {1,2,6,2,7,9,4,2,5,7,3}`

Each array can be a different size.

I need to check if the arrays have matching elements and put them in a new array. The result in this case should be:

`array[] = {2,2,2,5,7,4}`

And I need to do it in **O(n.log(n) + m.log(m))**.

I know there is a way to do with merge sorting or put one of the array in a hash array but I really don't know how to implement it.

I will really appreciate your help, thanks!!!

Comment: Why not loop over it?

Comment: i really didn't right any thing ... just thinking how to start this question :\

Comment: because its need  to nlogn + mlogm @OscarLundberg

Comment: Why is the result 2,2,2,5,7,4? That order doesn't seem to make any sense no matter how you process it

Comment: Never Ask , before doing it yourself , or you wont learn anything .

Comment: the order of the new array can be anything @musefan

Comment: @SurajJain i tried some stuff but dont know what is the correct way to do it

Comment: yes the new array is correct 
i have the number 2 3 times in the array a and 3 times in the array b
so {2,2,2.....

Comment: It looks like you are only adding elements from array `a`, which occur in array `b`.

Comment: Is this homework? If so it should be stated as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have already figured out you can use merge sort (implementing it is beyond the scope of this answer, I suppose you can find a solution on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) or searching on Stack Overflow) so that you can get `nlogn + mlogm` complexity supposing `n` is the size of the first array and `m` is the size of another.

Let's call the first array `a` (with the size `n`) and the second one `b` (with size `m`). First sort these arrays (merge sort would give us `nlogn + mlogm` complexity). And now we have:

`a[n] // {2,2,2,4,5,7,8}` and `b[n] // {1,2,2,2,3,4,5,6,7,7,9}`

Supposing `n <= m` we can simply iterate simulateously comparing coresponding values:

But first lets allocate array `int c[n];` to store results (you can print to the console instead of storing if you need). And now the loop itself:

```
 int k = 0;  // store the new size of c array!
 for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < n && j < m; )
 {
     if (a[i] == b[j])
     {
         // match found, store it
         c[k] = a[i];
         ++i; ++j; ++k;
     }
     else if (a[i] > b[j])
     {
         // current value in a is leading, go to next in b
         ++j;
     }
     else
     {
         // the last possibility is a[i] < b[j] - b is leading
         ++i;
     }
}
```

**Note:** the loop itself is `n+m` complexity at worst (remember `n <= m` assumption) which is less than for sorting so overal complexity is `nlogn + mlogm`. Now you can iterate `c` array (it's size is actually `n` as we allocated, but the number of elements in it is `k`) and do what you need with that numbers.

Answer (score 0):

From the way that you explain it the way to do this would be to loop over the shorter array and check it against the longer array. Let us assume that A is the shorter array and B the longer array. Create a results array C.

1. Loop over each element in A, call it I
2. If I is found in B, remove it from B and put it in C, break out of the test loop.
3. Now go to the next element in A.

This means that if a number I is found twice in A and three times in B, then I will only appear twice in C. Once you finish, then every number found in both arrays will appear in C the number of times that it actually appears in both.

I am carefully not putting in suggested code as your question is about a method that you can use. You should figure out the code yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I would be inclined to take the following approach:

1) Sort array B. There are many well published sort algorithms to do this, as well as several implementations in various generally available libraries.

2) Loop through array A and for each element do a binary search (or other suitable algorithm) on array B for a match. If a match is found, remove the element from array B (to avoid future matches) and add it to the output array.

Comment: The complexity for this algorithm is *O((n+m).log(m))*. Sorting both arrays yields the expected complexity and handles duplicates more accurately.

Comment: Thanks, chqrlie. I never learnt how to calculate the order of an algorithm. I guess sorting both arrays reduces the order of the matching since you can remember previous position and only search forwards.

Comment: after sorting both arrays, the matching can be done in linear time, not adding to the complexity. See Yuriy Ivaskevych's answer for details.